# Iterating over JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cookies

I'm having some troubles iterating in a json object. 
I'm currently saving the table properties of a some web page in a cookie.
The value of the cookie is an array of objects which I serialize.
The typical value of an array with 2 entries is something like:

```
cookieValue=["{ "PageID": "1391", "PageSize": "100"}", "{ "PageID": "2341", "PageSize": "50"}"]
```

My problem is iterating in this array now. I want to be able to check if there is any duplicate entry to update its PageSize (if applicable) or to read it in order to set the page size when a user goes back to the same page.

I've tried this so far:

```
for (var key in cookieValue) {
   if(cookieValue.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
      console.log(key + " -> " + cookieValue[key]);
   }
}
```

which give me an output like:

```
0 -> { "PageID": "1391_tabela", "PageSize": "100"}
1 -> { "PageID": "1391_tabela", "PageSize": "50"}
2 -> { "PageID": "1391_tabela", "PageSize": "10"}
```

My question is how am i able to access the value of PageID in each entry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: cookieValue[key]["PageID"] ?

Comment: "is something like" — What is it really? What you've provided is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: One week later you didn't provided any further more informations nor accepted any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to get the object by the PageId. Here is a function

```
function getPageById(pageId) {
     for (var pageObj in cookieValue) {
          if (pageObj.PageId === pageId)
               return pageObj;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but I think you should just use

`cookieValue[key]["PageID"]`

together:

```
for (var key in cookieValue) {
   if(cookieValue.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
      console.log(key + " -> " + cookieValue[key] + " -> " + cookieValue[key]["PageID"]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to access the value of PageId in each entry, you can view example here :

```
var cookieValue=[{ "PageID": "1391", "PageSize": "100"}, { "PageID": "2341", "PageSize": "50"}];



for (key in cookieValue) {
alert(cookieValue[key]["PageID"]);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/smt2hbzg)

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate the data using a javascript array for easier code.

One way that should work for you:

- convert your JSON into a javascript array using:

var mycookieArray = JSON.parse(cookieValue);

- Iterate through it with:

  for(String s : myCookieArray)
    {
      console.log(s.PageID);
    }